# CSV File Not Writing ByteString correctly

Tags: python, csv, serial-port, pyserial

My question is about writing bytestrings read from serial ports correctly to a CSV file.

This snippet of code works correctly, and `b'\x10\xa3!\x00\x05\x02\xd0\x00\x01T\x10\x03'` is written correctly to the file. The `debugData` is of `<class 'bytes'>`.

I am on the Linux platform.

```
with open("test.csv", mode = 'w') as debug_file:
    debug_writer = csv.writer(debug_file)
    debugData = b'\x10\xa3!\x00\x05\x02\xd0\x00\x01T\x10\x03'
    print(type(debugData))
    debug_writer.writerow([debugData])
```

With this snippet of code, it doesn't work correctly. `debugData` (read from the serial port) is still `b'\x10\xa3!\x00\x05\x02\xd0\x00\x01T\x10\x03'`, and of `<class 'bytes'>`.

```
serCom4 = serial.Serial(port = '/dev/ttyUSB4', baudrate = 926100, timeout = 3)
serCom4.write(b'\x10\xD0\x00\x00\x04\x01\x01\x01\xD5\x10\x03') # packet is sent to trigger serial port message sent back. However, `test.csv` contains nothing.
 

start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < 20:
    with open("test.csv", mode = 'w') as debug_file:
    
        if serCom4.in_waiting:
            debugData = serCom4.readline()
            print(debugData)
            print(type(debugData))
            debug_writer = csv.writer(debug_file)
            debug_writer.writerow([debugData])
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: What goes wrong?

Comment: Your explanation seems to omit the steps in the middle. Unless a loopback or echoback mechanism is built, applications will not read the data written on the serial port from the same port. Please add if you are building a loopback or echoback mechanism, and if so, what kind of mechanism it is. If it is echo back, collect a trace of what was written on the serial port on the other party's device side, display it, and compare it.

Comment: @kunif, Yes, this is an echoback mechanism using its own set of protocols. The device (within 20 seconds), only returns the debugData = `b'\x10\xa3!\x00\x05\x02\xd0\x00\x01T\x10\x03'`, as shown by the print statements. So the trace would only show that one bytestring. I'm wondering how it is not written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Binary data is probably not going to be compatible with the CSV format. I would recommend you convert the data into HEX which is compatible. This could be easily converted correctly back into binary if needed when reading the CSV file back in.

Conversion to hex can be done using the `.hex()` function ([Python 3.5 onwards](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex))

You probably would want to move the file creation to outside the loop. In this example, it also shows how a time stamp could be added (mainly to show how a second column could be added to the CSV file).

```
serCom4 = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB4', baudrate=926100, timeout=3)
serCom4.write(b'\x10\xD0\x00\x00\x04\x01\x01\x01\xD5\x10\x03') 
 
start_time = time.time()

with open("test.csv", "w", newline="") as debug_file:
    debug_writer = csv.writer(debug_file)
    debug_writer.writerow(["Time", "Data"])     # Example CSV header
    
    while (current_time := time.time() - start_time) < 20:
        if serCom4.in_waiting:
            debugData = serCom4.readline()
            debug_writer.writerow([f"{current_time:.1f}", debugData.hex()])
```

This would give you an output CSV file such as:

```
Time,Data
2.1,10a321000502d00001541003
```

You should also open your file using `newline=""` to avoid extra blank lines being created.

(Note: the `:=` operator is available in Python 3.7 onwards)

---

This could then be read back in as follows:

```
with open("test.csv") as debug_file:
    debug_reader = csv.reader(debug_file)
    header = next(debug_reader)
    print(header)
    
    for row in debug_reader:
        debug_data = bytes.fromhex(row[1])
        print(f"{row[0]:3}  {debug_data}")
```

Which would display:

```
['Time', 'Data']
1.2  b'\x10\xa3!\x00\x05\x02\xd0\x00\x01T\x10\x03'
```